# Is there a way to style add_menu_page() in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the `add-menu-page` function to add some kind of welcome page for my WordPress theme. Is there any way that I can style what is inside the page not using inline styling, or am I using `add-menu-page` for the wrong purpose?

Comment: Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ for the `add_menu_page` function. You are clearly using it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty straightforward. Here's what I'd do:

1. Create the CSS file
2. Enqueue the CSS file using `admin_enqueue_scripts` using code like [this answer from the WP Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7282/146514).

Repeating that code here just in case the other answer is removed:

```php
function my_admin_enqueue( $hook_suffix ) {
    if( 'appearance_page_theme-options' === $hook_suffix ) {       
        wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/theme-settings.css');        
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue', 10 );
```